# RTMP Proxy Server

Tags: nginx, proxy, load-balancing, failover, rtmp

I have an application which uses both HTTP (content data) and RTMP (video streams) for communications. An nginx server is configured for load balancing and proxying incoming client requests. It works well with HTTP & HTTPS protocols. The issue is with proxying RTMP requests. Since ngnix is not an RTMP proxy server i am struck. Is there a way out there with my current set up ? Can any one suggest a viable option here ?

Comment: There is an unofficial nginx rtmp module in this [github repo](https://github.com/arut/nginx-rtmp-module)

Answer (score 1):

you can proxy by using the rtmp module in the dmz and adding applications with the same name as another rtmp server

```
    application myVideos {

            live on;
            pull rtmp://<ip address>/myVideos;

    }
```